# How can I get command line arguments in a Qt Installer Framework script?

Tags: qt-installer

I am writing a Qt Installer Framework script, and I would like to allow the user to launch the installer with arguments and then apply those arguments in various ways.  For example, a switch to auto accept the EULA, a means to directly pass the target directory, a list of the components to be installed, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax to pass arguments to QIFW installer is Key=Value.

You can provide command line argument like below

```
YouInstaller.exe Arg1=true
```

Then you can get this value in Component or Controller script as below

```
var Arg1 = installer.value('Arg1')
```

[installer QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html)

[Controller Script](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html)